# Using backbone for one page and jquery for all sub pages

Tags: jquery, web-applications, backbone.js, requirejs

I currently have a multi-page web application that uses jquery.

I would like to create a landing page that will act as a single page web application. I started updating the whole application to use backbone. I have done this by creating additional routes/view files in order to run the jQuery. However with this method I'm not actually using any backbone in the other views and so feels wasteful.

I am re-planning the web app structure with the aim to be more efficient, and looking for help! I have started using requirejs to load my dependencies.

I was thinking I could use two layouts: one for the single page web app (to include backbone js), and another for all the sub-pages (which will have the jquery). Is this a reasonable way of structuring my project? I am currently using require

Comment: by sub-pages do you mean pages with static contents like about us page something like that?

Comment: I generally view Backbone simply as a way to organize my code. I view jQuery as a library to facilitate DOM manipulation and abstraction of browser differences. In other words, I don't see jQuery as a tool for organizing code, so I guess my question would be, how are you organizing the sub-pages. If they don't really require any organization, than Backbone probably isn't necessary.